# Can twilio send a MMS photo from a USA number?

Tags: twilio

"Sending picture messages in United States

At this time sending/receiving picture messages over Twilio US long codes is not supported. "

I noticed this in the documentation, but not sure when this documentation was generated 
since Twilio has been around a few years now.

If it's still not supported in USA, when will it be?

Comment: UPDATED:  DEC. 2015 --  https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-send-or-receive-mms-messages  -- Can I send or receive MMS messages?

Yes, as long as your Twilio phone number is MMS-enabled. Currently Twilio offers MMS-enabled long code phone numbers -At this time, MMS messaging can only be sent within US and Canada. International MMS messaging outside these two countries is not yet supported, however MMS messages sent internationally will be converted to SMS text messages with a URL link to the media. MMS messages sent in the US or Canada to unsupported carriers will also be sent via SMS.

Answer (score 1):

FYI:  https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/09/introducing-twilio-mms-nt.html

Twilio now supports [picture messaging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) on US Long Codes

Answer (score 0):

Twilio supports sending picture SMS since late last year. Check their [page](https://www.twilio.com/mms) for more details.

Comment: Widespread Support
Picture messages work on Canadian phone numbers as well as US short codes.  Seems like you need an expensive short code for it to work in USA